# Add a paragraph symbol to section, but not to subsection

Tags: sectioning

How can you add a paragraph sign to a section?
I know that this can be done by writing

`\renewcommand{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}}`

in the preamble.

However, if you do so in this way, the paragraph sign will also be set in the subsection. Is there a way that the paragraph sign will only be added to the section, but not to the subsection?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to be able to cross-reference section-level headings by their numbers, i.e., *without* the `\S` prefix, I would like to suggest you proceed by adopting an approach I first encountered several years ago, on pp. 26f of *The LaTeX Companion*. It works by modifying the low-level macro `\section@cntformat`, which controls how counters associated with sectioning headers are displayed in the sectioning header itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% See pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed.) 
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default appearance
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\S\thesection\quad}   % section level 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section} \label{sec:A}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second Section} \label{sec:B}

As we argued in section \ref{sec:A}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I included the suggestion in my document. This works fine. I have still the problem that the sections in my document are subdivided like this

Comment: @dieter -- "... are subdivided like this" -- like *what*? Please be more specific.